Finding minimum value in given range efficiently
I have function that takes a number n that represents number of servers and another parameter represents a list of requests
Initially servers will hold values 0 of size n.
For each request, requests[i], find the server index which has minimum value in the range [0, requests[i]], store this index into result, also increment the value by one at that server index. If multiple servers have same minimum in range [0, requests[i]] then pick the one that has less index position.
Example:
n = 5 and requests = [3, 2, 3, 2, 4]

Result :
[0,1,2,0,3]

Explanation:
a) requests[0] = 3
n=5 so servers = [0,0,0,0,0]
pick server that has minimum value in range [0, request[0]] = [0,3], the servers in range [0,3] are [0,0,0]
pick server at index 0, and store it in result = [0]. also increment server[0]++ so servers array is now [1,0,0,0,0]

b) requests[1] = 2
servers = [1,0,0,0,0]
pick server that has minimum value in range [0, request[1]] = [0,2], the servers in range [0,2] are [1,0,0]
pick server at index 1, and store it in result = [0, 1]. also increment server[1]++ so servers array is now [1,1,0,0,0]

c) requests[2] = 3
servers[1,1,0,0,0]
range [0,3] => [1,1,0,0]
pick server at index 2, so result = [0,1,2], now servers = [1,1,1,0,0]

d)  requests[3] = 2
servers[1,1,1,0,0]
range [0,2] => [1,1,1]
pick server at index 0, so result = [0,1,2, 0], now servers = [2,1,1,0,0]

e)  requests[4] = 4
servers[2,1,0,0,0]
range [0,4] => [2,1,1,0,0]
pick server at index 3, so result = [0,1,2,0, 3], now servers = [2,1,1,1,0]

Finally result is [0, 1,2,0,3]

Constraints:
1 <= n <= 10^5
0 <= requests[i] < n

Here is my code in O(n^2) time complexity
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(5, Arrays.asList(3,2,3,2, 4))); //[0,1,2,0,3]
    }
     public static List<Integer> solve(int n, List<Integer> requests) {
        int[] servers = new int[n];
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int e : requests) {
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int idx = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= e; i++) {
                if (servers[i] < min) {
                    min = servers[i];
                    idx = i;
                }
            }
            result.add(idx);
            servers[idx]++;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
}

How to solve this in less time complexity?

If the data is not sorted beforehand you will have to scan it completely. But do you have to use nested loops? If you can do it in a single pass you'd have O(n).

Quick-select may be faster, but repeated calls will certainly have a better solution.

"the servers in range [0,3] are [0,0,0]" - "the servers in range [0,2] are [1,0,0]" - Why are they equally long?

Your code is not O(n^2), as the runtime depends on the number of requests, which is unlimited.

O(n+r), where r is the number of requests.
Note that servers is monotonically decreasing. So for each request e, the minimum value in servers[0..e] is the value servers[e]. We just need to find the first index where that value occurs. For that, we keep track of the first index for each occurring value. Attempt This Online!
     public static List<Integer> solve(int n, List<Integer> requests) {
        int[] servers = new int[n];
        int[] first = new int[requests.size()];
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int e : requests) {
            int min = servers[e];
            int idx = first[min++]++;
            result.add(idx);
            servers[idx]++;
            if (idx == 0 || servers[idx-1] > min)
                first[min] = idx;
        }
        return result;
    }

Python version with a bigger test (n=1000 and r=10000, comparing the result with a naive solution's):
def solve_fast(n, requests):
    servers = [0] * n
    first = {0: 0}
    result = []
    for r in requests:
        s = servers[r]
        i = first[s]
        result.append(i)
        servers[i] += 1
        first[s] += 1
        if i == 0 or servers[i-1] > s+1:
            first[s+1] = i
    return result

def solve_naive(n, requests):
    servers = [0] * n
    result = []
    for r in requests:
        s = min(servers[:r+1])
        i = servers.index(s)
        result.append(i)
        servers[i] += 1
    return result

import random

def test(n, requests):
    expect = solve_naive(n, requests) 
    result = solve_fast(n, requests) 
    print(result == expect)
    print(str(expect)[-80:])
    print(str(result)[-80:])
    print()

n = 5
requests = [3, 2, 3, 2, 4]
test(n, requests)

n = 1000
requests = random. choices(range(n), k=n*10)
test(n, requests)

Sample output (Attempt This Online!):
True
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3]

True
, 125, 937, 202, 421, 38, 310, 543, 874, 782, 311, 544, 875, 126, 783, 312, 203]
, 125, 937, 202, 421, 38, 310, 543, 874, 782, 311, 544, 875, 126, 783, 312, 203]


This can be solved by using a segment tree that stores the lowest index of the minimum value in each node. Updates and queries are both O(log N).

Seems slow and complicated :-P

@nocomment Most people practicing competitive programming have a segment tree template handy anyway, so this is actually a low effort path. :)

Hmm, maybe. I guess that might've changed since I was active. But still slower, I think.
